# How to refech queries in wagmi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, wagmi

I think Wagmi uses `react-query` under the hood. So I want to refresh queries whenever and wherever I wanted using `invalidateQueries` method like we use to do with `react-query`.

Here is the query that I want to refetch:

```js
  import { useContractRead } from 'wagmi';

  const balance = useContractRead({
    address: --random-adress--,
    abi: random.abi,
    functionName: 'balanceOf',
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log('balanceOf refeched');
    },
    cacheTime: 0,
    staleTime: 0,
    scopeKey: 'balanceOf',
  });
```

And here is the implementation of invalidation:

```js
import { useQueryClient } from 'wagmi';

function App() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['balanceOf'] });
      }}
    >
      Click Me!
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

First I thought the function name is also query key but it's not worked. Then I added scopeKey hoping it would be the queryKey but it still not works.

Version: wagmi@1.^*

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `refetch` from `useContractRead` returned value.
you can create a custom hook named `useGetBalance` and then use It all over the place.

useGetBalance hook :

```
export const useGetBalance = ()=>{
return useContractRead({
address: --random-adress--,
abi: random.abi,
functionName: 'balanceOf',
onSuccess: () => {
  console.log('balanceOf refeched');
},
cacheTime: 0,
staleTime: 0,
scopeKey: 'balanceOf',
});
```

usage :

```
function App() {
const {refetch:refetchBalance} = useGetBalance();

 return (
 <button
  onClick={() => {
    refetchBalance?.()
  }}
>
  Refetch !
</button>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Let's say I use this on my header component to show my balance. If I wanted to update this balance after I make a transaction or something on a diffrent component, I need to pass that refetch function all the way trough that component. The 'invalidateQueries' api is much clean way to done this.

Comment: @Nightvision I think this also might be an option :
https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractRead#watch-optional